# Custom Query > post__in => $page_id (multiple page not show / just show 1 page)

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
global $redux_demo; 
$page_id = $redux_demo[input_id];

$query_page = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'page',
    'post__in'=>array($page_id)
));
?>
```

its show just single page, not multiple pages.

```
var_dump($page_id); // output '192, 185, 188, 150'    // include = 'punctuation'
```

if manual input = **array(192, 185, 188, 150)** show selected pages.

How can I fixed this problem `$page_id` ???

Answer (score 0):

The `post__in` parameter expects an `array` of IDs, and you're passing it a `string` (see [WP_Query - Post & Page Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for more details.

So, you need to convert `$redux_demo[input_id]` into an array first:

```
global $redux_demo;

// Convert input into an array, and remove whitespaces
$page_id = array_map( 'trim', explode(',', $redux_demo['input_id']) );

$query_page = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in' => $page_id
));
```

Also, it seems you're missing some quotes here: `$redux_demo[input_id]`. Shouldn't it be `$redux_demo['input_id']` instead?